# hide a row of dynamically created Table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have reservation system where reservations are being shown on a bootstrap modal on clicking on button on my page. Modal displays a table of reservations with a option of "Cancel".

If Cancel occurs, I need to hide or delete the row of that table on the modal.
Tried .hide() on  element or  element , nothing is working. I suspect since it was created dynamically, I need to find some other option to achieve it.

I don't want to refresh the modal ( close and show it with again). It would be cool if I find something which slides up the row.

any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<div class=table-responsive><table id='mytable' class=table table-hover><tr><th>Emp ID</th><th>Name</th><th>From Date & Time</th><th>To Date & Time</th><th>Action</th></tr><tr class="trCancel1920032014-04-03T18:00:00.000Z2014-04-03T19:00:00.000Z"><td>192003</td><td>Somenath Ghosh</td><td>03-Apr-2014  14:00</td><td>03-Apr-2014  15:00</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnDelete" data-loading-text="Wait..."id="btnCancel_192003_2014-04-03T18:00:00.000Z_2014-04-03T19:00:00.000Z">Cancel</button></td></tr></div></table>
```

Comment: Show some conde please

Comment: doesn't `$("#yourtable td").hide()` works?

Comment: It's easy to hide a table row using jQuery, but we can't help you really at all without you showing us what the generated HTML looks like.  You will have to come up with some sort of CSS selector that matches the row you want to hide and then do `$("selector for your row").hide();`.  It is no more involved than that.  Also, all good questions  like this show us what you tried too.

Comment: I have added the code. I tried $("trCancel1920032014-04-03T18:00:00.000Z2014-04-03T19:00:00.000Z").hide(). It did not work.